# Create dynamically nested MenuItem in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I would like to know if I can create dynamically a nested MenuItem with C#. To be more precise I have the following code:

```
public override List<object> ContextMenu
        {
            get
            {

                var result = new List<object>
                {
                    new MenuItem
                    {
                        Header = "Drive",
                        Command = Drive_Command,
                    }, 
                };

                var message = new ContextMenuBuild<HostVM>(this);
                Messenger.Send(message);
                AddExternalContextMenu(result, message.Items);
                return result;
            }
}
```

What I want to achieve is a nested MenuItem, the "mySubMenuItem". With wpf would be like this:

```
<ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Drive" Command="Drive_Command">
                <MenuItem Header="mySubMenuItem"/>   
            </MenuItem> 
</ContextMenu>
```

In order to be able to have a submenu like n the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can.

```
var mi = new MenuItem(){
    Header = "Drive"
};

var subMi = new MenuItem(){
    Header = "mySubMenuItem"
};
mi.Items.Add(subMi);
```